# Wasabi how to create new user

Tags: ab-testing, intuit-wasabi

I can't seem to find a way to create a new user in Wasabi.

Tried in the UI:

- Users -> Add User -> enter email -> Verify -> shows X
- Applications -> Add User -> enter email -> Verify -> shows X

I also went through the documentation here: https://intuit.github.io/wasabi/v1/guide/index.html#overview, as well as API docs but there's not much about adding new users.

Currently, I can log in using admin:admin

How to create new uesrs?

Answer (score 1):

Wasabi uses an internal lookup to check whether the email of the new user is allowed (for example you could restrict the users to only your company's employees).

This is done by providing your own implementation of a `UserDirectory`. The current default implementation is quite restrictive in the sense that it only allows the predefined users (have a look at the `userDirectory.properties` for the available users). That is why the new Users you want to add are not allowed.

The solution to your issue would be to provide an own implementation of the `UserDirectory` that allows for the right set of emails and usernames. Note that this implementation could also be written in a way that is simply allowing all the email addresses, although that may not be recommended from a security related standpoint.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I believe Andrea's question is accurate if what you want to do is to implement your own authentication system to a production Wasabi.  However, if you are just trying to see how the Wasabi UI works when you have different users with different permissions, there are 4 built-in users that you can use (e.g., they are users that work in the stock implementation of UserDirectory).  They are admin:admin, wasabi_reader:wasabi01, wasabi_writer:wasabi01 and wasabi_admin:wasabi01.  Note that you can login as those users with those usernames and passwords.  However, if you want to give those users privileges, you would login as admin and then go to the Users tab and click on Add User.  What you need to provide there is an email address, and the email addresses for those users follows the pattern wasabi_reader@example.com .  You can then give them permissions for applications as Wasabi controls access at an application level.  Also please note that the names are just names, that is, the wasabi_writer, for example, doesn't have to have write permissions.